# Custom Spring Security using annotation: REST api to pass in username password instead of login dialog box

Tags: java, rest, spring-security, annotations, spring-java-config

I am trying to secure my REST based application using Spring Security using no XML. This is what I have so far -

-- AppConfig.java

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration 
@ComponentScan("com.trans.*") 
@EnableWebMvc   
@Import({SecurityConfig.class})
public class AppConfig {  
}
```

-- WebAppInitializer.java --

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer  {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

-- SecurityConfig.java --

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("john").password("123456").roles("USER");
      auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("123456").roles("ADMIN");
      auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("dba").password("123456").roles("DBA");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
        .and().formLogin()
        .and().logout().logoutUrl("/j_spring_security_logout")
        .and().httpBasic();
    }
}
```

-- SpringSecurityInitializer.java --

```
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SpringSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

After implementing this much I got the basic Spring functionality working -

1. After going into a browser if I enter htttp://localhost:8080/Spring4/user/1 browser popsup a   login dialog to enter username and password.
2. I can logout by htttp://localhost:8080/Spring4/logout

**What I am trying to do is -**

1. Instead of the dialog I can pass in username and password as json.
2. should return a token so that on the next api calls I don't have to pass in username and password.

WHat should be the apporach to achieve this?
--Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Spring security OAuth 2.0 to secure rest services.

http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/

Answer (score 0):

1) This dialog appears as a result bad login attempt. To avoid showing pop-up at client side, you should create your own `BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint` implementation like this:

```
@Service
public class YourBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {

  @Override
  public void commence(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
      final AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, authException.getMessage());
  }
}
```

This will avoid putting `WWW-Authenticate` header in your HTTP response, which causes the pop-up.

Providing username/password in json formatted body needs object mapping which is not performed in authentication phase yet. As you already supported HTTP Basic authentication in your `SecurityConfig` class, passing Base64 encoded username/password in HTTP request's `Authentication` header will cover your requirement.

2) By default, Spring security creates stateful sessions, thus you do not need an extra implementation. However, if you need to force client to authenticate for every request in future, you can switch to stateless policy as below:

```
http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
```